# How to find the count of repeated numbers in an given array and return the output as an object

Tags: javascript, foreach

I have been asked with this question in one of my recent interviews.
For a given array, say, `Arr[2,2,4,3,4,2,3,2,4]`
write a javascript function to return an object with the count of each number in the above array, like

```
countArr={2:4,3:2,4:3}
```

After a lot of google I have ended up with the below code which is returning the correct data.

```js
var uniqueCount = [2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2];
var count = {};
uniqueCount.forEach(function(i) {
  count[i] = (count[i] || 0) + 1;
});
console.log(count);
```

As I said this works fine! `Output: {2: 4, 3: 2, 4: 2}`
Well, a code without proper understanding of whats happening in back ground means nothing for a developer :)

Can anyone please help me out to understand how this actually work?

Comment: `count[i] = (count[i] || 0) + 1;` means _if there is already a count for digit `i` set count[i] to that value, otherwise set it to 0 (initialise it) then add 1 to whatever is in count[i] now_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's actually simple. Let's go step by step.

```
var count = {};
```

Declares a JS object. It's basically a key-value store. You can access the value of a key by writing `count[key]`. Then store or retrieve the value.

Consider this simple example:

```
var count = {}
count['ok'] = 3
console.log(count)
```

It outputs `{ ok: 3 }`

Now replace 'ok' with a number, and you get the structure of the rest of the code : keys are added to the object for each number found in the array, or are incremented when they exists.

Let's continue with the code.

```
uniqueCount.forEach(function(i) {
  // code here is called for each entry in the uniqueCount array, i being the current value.
});
```

And finally, the magic happens here:

```
count[i] = (count[i] || 0) + 1;
```

From left to right, it reads: assign to the `i` property of the `count` object a value that is it's current value or 0 if there is none, then add 1. So if the `i` number was already seen it takes the previous value and adds 1; if it wasn't seen, it takes 0 and adds one.

So when you console.log(count) you get the values for all of those properties.

Comment: Awesome! A lucid explanation. Thank you Arnaud!

Answer (score 1):

The main work of creating an object with each of the unique array element's count
is happening in the following block:

```
uniqueCount.forEach(function(i) {
   count[i] = (count[i] || 0) + 1;
});
```

Here we are iterating over each of the elements in the array like we do in a 'for loop'. I hope you are familiar with the working of a 'for loop'. Then, we are passing each element of the array in a function.

```
count[i] = (count[i] || 0) +1;
```

can be written as:

```
if(count[i]) {
   count[i] = count[i] + 1;
} else {
   count[i] = 1;
}
```

Hope that helps you to understand the code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is only one line that confused you:

`count[i] = (count[i] || 0) + 1;` means

> If there is already a count for digit `i` set count[i] to that value, otherwise set it to 0 (initialise it) then add 1 to whatever is in count[i] now

Can be rewritten like this to make it more understandable - note I changed the variable, array and object names

```js
var array = [2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2];
var uniqueCount = {};
array.forEach(function(digit) {
  if (uniqueCount[digit]) uniqueCount[digit]++; // if counter for the digit exist, add 1 
  else uniqueCount[digit] = 1; // else initialise it to 1
});
console.log(uniqueCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code uses an object as a map from number values to integer counts of their frequency.

```js
1.  var uniqueCount = [2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2];
2.  var count = {};
3.  uniqueCount.forEach(function(i) {
4.    count[i] = (count[i] || 0) + 1;
5.  });
6.  console.log(count);
```

Line 1: Declare variable `uniqueCount` and assign to it a new array of numbers.

Line 2: Declare variable `count` and assign to it a new, empty object.

Line 3: Run an anonymous function once for each number in `uniqueCount`.

Line 4: Assign to a property on `count`, named with the current number in the array: one plus the existing value of the property, or if the property does not already exist, zero.

Line 6: Print the final state of `count`.

The code would be clearer if the variable `i` in the anonymous function was named `n` (or something) because `i` (yes, I know it means "integer" here) usually means "index", and here, it is *not* the index.

Note that in JavaScript simply assigning a value to a property on an object will create that property if it does not already exist.